# Difference between translations of "Piglet"

Tags: vocabulaire

I have translated "piglet" into French. I have found three translations: "porcelet m, petit cochon m, cochonnet m".

From Larousse:

> porcelet = "Jeune porc ; goret."
>
> petit cochon = {no entry}
>
> cochonnet = "Boule plus petite que les autres, et qui sert de but dans le jeu de boules (synonyme but) ; le jeu de boules lui-même."

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 5):

Your definition of *cochonnet* from [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cochonnet/16848) is right. According to [le dictionnaire historique de la langue française](http://catalogue.bm-lyon.fr/?fn=ViewNotice&Style=Portal3&q=899998), it is said :

> En ancien français, cochon a produit cochonnet n. m. (XIIIe siècle) dont le sens de "cochon de lait" a été repris par porcelet, et qui garde des sens analogiques réalisant l'idée d'une petite boule ronde, désignant couramment une petite boule servant de but au jeu de boules (1542).

*Porcelet*, *goret* are correct translations for "piglet". You can use *cochonnet* as well, but it is an old french word and it will be understood as the "Jack" from the *[Pétanque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9tanque)* game.

*Petit cochon* means "a pig of small size", it can also mean "a baby pig" in spoken language. According to me (native speaker), I would use *Porcelet* and *petit cochon* depending on the tone.

Answer (score 3):

"Porcelet" means a pig in its young age.

"Petit cochon" may be translated by "little pig" (petit in terms of size) or "young pig" (petit in terms of age).

"Cochonnet" is a very specific term used to talk about the small ball acting as goal in the game of [pétanque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9tanque).

Comment: *Cochonnet* means *piglet* too. But yes, it's used most of the time for this ball at *pétanque*.